# Sql Server Agent Error?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Error authenticating proxy NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users system error: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

Any ideas ?

Comment: How is this not self-explanatory? You're supplying invalid credentials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Authenticated Users cannot be a proxy because it is a pseudo group/Builtin SID.

Only local users, or domain users can be proxy accounts, not builtin groups, local groups (aliases) or domain or enterprise groups.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have put a `unknown user name or bad password.`

Another thing that you might forget is the `DOMAIN` on the `user name` part.